# Python Pandas: how to overwrite subset of a dataframe with a subset of another dataframe?

Tags: pandas, merge, subset

Given `df1` and `df2`, how do I get `df3` using pandas, where `df3` has `df1` elements:

```
[11, 12, 21, 22]
```

in the place of `df2` elements

```
[22, 23, 32, 33]
```

Condition: indexes of row 1 & 2 in `df1` are the same as indexes of row 2  & 3 in `df2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`DataFrame.loc` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Small example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"data":[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"data":[11,12,13,14,15]})
df3 = df1.copy()
df3.loc[3:4] = df2.loc[3:4]

df3
   data
0     1
1     2
2     3
3    14
4    15
```

Comment: One more question - instead of locations, if I want to use the index and a subset of column names to merge values in two dataframes?